# Kusto Query Earliest and Latest date in the Past 21 days

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

So I am new to kusto and I am trying to get the min and max dates of the past 21 days in a kusto query and I want to project those min and max dates.

How do I modify this simple query to get the min and max dates of the past 21 days?

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >= ago(21d)
| project timestamp
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`summarize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) with [`max()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/max-aggfunction) and [`min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/min-aggfunction) like this:

```js
customEvents
| where timestamp >= ago(21d)
| summarize min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
```